# Какова роль параметра order в NumPy массивах?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, numpy

Начал я учить numpy по английской документации, и в таких типах массивов как np.array(), np.empty_like() заметил параметр order, который принимает следующие значения: 'K','F','A', 'C'. В английской документации написано следующее:

```
order : {‘K’, ‘A’, ‘C’, ‘F’}, optional
Specify the memory layout of the array. If object is not an array, the newly created array will be in C
order (row major) unless ‘F’ is specified, in which case it will be in Fortran order (column major). If object
is an array the following holds.

order   no copy     copy=True
‘K’     unchanged   F & C order preserved, otherwise most similar order
‘A’     unchanged   F order if input is F and not C, otherwise C order
‘C’     C order     C order
‘F’     F order     F order
When copy=False and a copy is made for other reasons, the result is the same as if copy=True, with
some exceptions for A, see the Notes section. The default order is ‘K’.
```

что переводится примерно так: Укажите расположение памяти массива. Если объект не является массивом, то вновь созданный массив будет находиться в порядке C (строка major), если не указано значение ‘F’ - в этом случае он будет находиться в порядке Fortran (столбец major). Если объект является массивом то выполнится табличка что на картинке.

Даже с переводом я не понимаю, что оно делает на практике объясните кто на пальцах, пожалуйста.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Двумерные (и вообще многомерные) массивы могут храниться в памяти по-разному. Статические массивы в С и большинстве других языков хранятся по строкам, т.е. массив

```
A[0,0]  A[0,1]
A[1,0]  A[1,1]
```

Лежит упакованный как

```
A[0,0]  A[0,1]  A[1,0]  A[1,1]
```

А вот в Фортране принято хранение по  столбцам

```
A[0,0]  A[1,0]  A[0,1]  A[1,1]
```

Кроме того, части массива могут идти не сразу друг за другом, между ними может быть некое пустое место, например, на выравнивание адресов.

Вот ключи преобразования и контролируют, нужно ли перепаковывать массив из одного порядка в другой

Comment: А як це впливає на програму? Коли вона працює швидше a коли повільніше? И как перекладається Subok ?

Comment: Это нужно очень редко - например, если происходит взаимодействие с фортрановскими библиотеками.

Comment: И как перекладається Subok ?

Comment: Если на основе ndarray создан новый класс (sub-class), то его тип можно указывать в subok. Не создаёте - забейте.